# Анимация увеличения чисел при прокрутке страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Прокрутите вниз до блока с числами. Как сделать так чтобы с каждого блока считывалось численное значение и увеличивалось именно до того, которое прописано в html. Сейчас у меня в коде задано одно значения для всех

https://codepen.io/st-iv/pen/MBMVwW?editors=1010

```
$(function () { 
  var target_block = $(".advantage__info-item .num"); // Ищем блок 
  var blockStatus = true;  
  $(window).scroll(function() { 
    var scrollEvent = ($(window).scrollTop() > (target_block.position().top - $(window).height())); 
    if(scrollEvent && blockStatus) {  
      blockStatus = false; 
      $({numberValue: 0}).animate({numberValue: 19}, { 
        duration: 500, // Скорость анимации, где 500 - 0.5 одной секунды, то есть 500 миллисекунд 
        easing: "linear", 
        step: function(val) {  
          $(".advantage__info-item .num").html(Math.ceil(val)); // Блок, где необходимо сделать анимацию 
        } 
      }); 
    } 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: передать в атрибут элемента, с которого будет приниматься значение, например data-number и передать его в js

Comment: а как-то без атрибутов можно, мне кажется это ненужное усложнение. просто чтобы из тега p class="num" считывалось число было бы лучше

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял то тебе нужно именно это. Как это прикрутить к прокрутке я думаю сам додумаешься.

```js
function calcCount() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $('.number').length; i++) {
        var end = $('.number').eq(i).text();
        countStart(end, i);
    }
}

function countStart(end, i) {
    var start = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        $('.number').eq(i).text(++start);
        if (start == end) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 50);//скорость менять вот-тута
}
calcCount();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="number">4</p>
<p class="number">8</p>
<p class="number">16</p>
<p class="number">23</p>
<p class="number">45</p>
```