# Как сделать чтобы числа увеличивались от 0 до нужного числа?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, вёрстка

Как сделать чтобы числа увеличивались от 0 до нужного числа при прокрутке страницы ?

1. Увеличение чисел от 0 до сами можем указать число
2. Как только доходим до блока с цифрами они должны увеличиваться
3. В примере указана число 26
4. Увеличение будет от 0 до 26
5. Указать можно любое число и до этого числа будет прокрутка
6. Ссылка для наглядности как должно выглядеть
7. вот пример кода [Анимация увеличения чисел при прокрутке страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/869608/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B) скажите как прикрутить скролл ?

https://www.templatemonster.com/ru/demo/71650.html
 8. Как такое можно сделать ?

```css
.s-figure {
  background-image: url("../img/figure-img.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  padding-top: 159px;
  padding-bottom: 180px; }

.figure__title {
  color: #f9f9f9;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 347px;
  max-width: 347px;
  margin-bottom: 0; }

.figure-block {
  color: red;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center; }

.figure__text {
  color: red;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 30px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<section class="s-figure">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4">
    <div class="figure-block">
     Авторские<br> свидетельства;
     <p class="figure__text">
      26
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Эмм... а "нужное число" - это какое?) И что оно из себя будет представлять? Может % проскролленного расстояния?

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME https://www.templatemonster.com/ru/demo/71650.html

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME "нужное число  мы сами вводим

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/869608/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME Вы можете улучшить код чтобы работало при скролле ?

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME код выше https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/869608/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME у меня мало опыта в js как сделать правильно

Comment: Оставлю ссылку на http://demo.tinywall.net/numscroller/

Comment: @Pavel8289 не работает :((

Comment: @Pavel8289 можете сюда привести пример кода пожалуйста ?

Comment: @Pavel8289  спасибо еще раз, получилось, а код все же покажите чтобы вопрос закрыть :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного косячный но работает. И... должен быть способ получше, отключать событие, когда оно уже сработало... но я пока не знаю такого. Поэтому хотя бы через `return;` можно уменьшить кол-во лишних вычислений.

```js
(function(){

let counter = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');
let limit = 0; // Переменная, чтобы останавливать функцию, когда всё запустится.
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){  
  if( limit == counter.length ){ return; }
  
  for(let i = 0; i < counter.length; i++){
    let pos = counter[i].getBoundingClientRect().top; //Позиция блока, считая сверху окна
    let win = window.innerHeight - 40; // На 40 пикселей меньше, чем высота окна
    if( pos < win && counter[i].dataset.stop === "0" ){
      counter[i].dataset.stop = 1; // Останавливаем перезапуск счета в этом блоке
      let x = 0;
      limit++; // Счетчик будет запущен, увеличиваем переменную на 1
      let int = setInterval(function(){
        // Раз в 60 миллисекунд будет прибавляться 50-я часть нужного числа
        x = x + Math.ceil( counter[i].dataset.to / 50 ); 
        counter[i].innerText = x;
        if( x > counter[i].dataset.to ){
          //Как только досчитали - стираем интервал.
          counter[i].innerText = counter[i].dataset.to;
          clearInterval(int);
        }
      }, 60);
    }
  }
});

})();
```

```css
.counter {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 400px 0 200px 0; 
  border: 2px solid orange;
  font-size: 30px; color: #045acf;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="counter" data-to="26" data-stop="0">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-to="1000" data-stop="0">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-to="2500000" data-stop="0">0</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, плагин скинули http://demo.tinywall.net/numscroller/

Comment: `function handleScroll(event) {...}` - функция, что записана при замыкании в вашем ответе. `window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);` - вешаем функцию обработчик. `window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);` - удаляем функцию обработчик.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const numberBlock = document.getElementById("numbers");
const endPoint = 40;
const speed = 5; // скорость, время за которое нужно произвести анимацию в сек
var scores = {
  score1: { score: 0,  end: 40 },
  score2: { score: 0,  end: 30 },
  score3: { score: 0,  end: 100 }
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  const numberBlockPos = numberBlock.offsetTop,
        winHeight = window.innerHeight;
  let winScrollTop = window.scrollY,
      scrollToElem = winScrollTop + winHeight,
      anamatedNumbers = false;
  
  if( (scrollToElem + 30 > numberBlockPos) && !anamatedNumbers) {
    TweenMax.to(scores.score1, speed, {score: scores.score1.end, onUpdate: updateHandler, onUpdateParams: [1]});
    TweenMax.to(scores.score2, speed, {score: scores.score2.end, onUpdate: updateHandler, onUpdateParams: [2]});
    TweenMax.to(scores.score3, speed, {score: scores.score3.end, onUpdate: updateHandler, onUpdateParams: [3]});
  }
});

function updateHandler(index) {
  let numberBlock = document.querySelector('.col[data-target="' + index  + '"] div');
  numberBlock.innerHTML = scores[`score${index}`].score.toFixed(0);
}
```

```css
#numbers {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.col {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<h2>Прокрутите страницу</h2>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="numbers">
  <div class="col" data-target="1">
    <h3>Увеличение числа 1</h3>
    <div>0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col" data-target="2">
    <h3>Увеличение числа 2</h3>
    <div>0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col" data-target="3">
    <h3>Увеличение числа 3</h3>
    <div>0</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
```

Как то так выходит на скорую руку. Дальше сами уже думаю разберетесь.

Comment: @Leks дополнил ответ

Comment: @Leks TweenMax по сути можете вынести в функцию, переделать чуть логику и в цикле вызывать эту функцию для каждого элемента.

Comment: @Leks jquery даже не подключен (или вы путаете с js принципиально, или не так поняли что-то)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94623/discussion-between--and-leks).